# Is creating an SPA web site using Angular renders ASP.NET Core views superfluous?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I've just begun learning Angular 2 and Typescript in order to create Single Page Application, and it seems to me that I'll be able to use either Angular (SPA) or ASP.NET Core views (traditional web application), but not both. Is that true ? I've spend lots of time learning ASP.NET Core views (tag helpers, view components, etc. I'll be glad to get some advice...

Comment: You can have an angular app embedded inside an asp.net core view, and it will function fine.  However, if you request a new core view from the server, you will be loading a new angular app (if one exists on that page) rather than using the existing app instance.

Comment: In all fairness the index page you use to load your angular 2 application is done in a razor view.  You can use both razor and angular at the same time, it isn't best practice, but it can be done quite effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition on @Kuncevic answer:

Using razor rendered pages for Angular is not advised.

Angular contains al the logic structs as: `if` and `foreach` loops.

If you would do this in razor you would break your model binding and when you update your angular models your page would not be updated.

### Advise

Either use angular and static angular pages + dotnet core as an API.

or use Dotnet core api + razor pages and don't use angular.

### downsides

If you use Angular and dynamically load in your data through api calls your page is no longer properly indexed by Search engines such as google, meaning: you lose all your SEO worth.

There are fixes/techniques that prerender the pages including the data for you. but you'd have to build/structure your page in the way these techniques want.

IF you need SEO. I would advise you to research this first!

Comment: Hi Joel,  of course I need SEO. However, I am not sure which path to take, as I am not much acquainted with SPA . Are there many asp.net developers who use SPA ? Is this approach considered preferable over traditional web developing + Ajax ?

Comment: @Isaac I'd advise you to check@Kuncevic s updated answer. You should give it a try. Otherwise go for ReactJs it has a way bigger community. Angular 2+ uses typescript classes and IOC. With react you can do things quick (and dirty) if you prefer it that way.

Comment: Does employing ReactJs instead of Angular require ASP.NET MVC (Razor, tag helpers, 
etc.) ? I know nothing about ReactJs, but let me state the following and you tell me if 
it's true or false:
1. I create an ASP.NET MVC app the old way
2. This assure that SEO is performed well
3. On the front end I use the ReactJs library to provide rich client experience through 
   AJAX, the same functionality we got in the past using jQuery

Many thanks

Comment: @Issac why use Spa: angular or ReactJs at all, where do you want to use it for. It sounds like you just need simple HTML pages with a bit of JavaScript instead of these spa frameworks?

Comment: @Joel Harkes The downsides you list are false nowadays.  While Google recommended using AJAX Crawling Scheme in 2009 for SEO, they discontinued it in 2015 and now recommend new sites steer clear because Google can effectively crawl JavaScript these days themselves.

Comment: @DavidRachwalik i happily change my answer based on what you say but i have not found any news articles or anything indicating this is true.

Comment: The [official announcement](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) came Oct 2015.  (Unfortunately?) Google made the new solution easy for us, so there won't be as many sites talking about it extensively.

The main takeaway is sites continuing the old method is ok, but understand it's deprecated and no longer in support.  Google didn't like developers needing to double their work with pre-renders and work-a-rounds.

Answer (score 2):

It is depends what you are trying to achieve but for the most cases you do not need to run any server side HTML renderers like ASPNET MVC under the hood of your Angular 2 application.

The best practice is to keep the SPA separate  and just to build API using server side technology, in you case ASPNET WebApi. This way your SPA will be completely decoupled from the server relying just on your API.

**UPDATE:**

Currently I am involving in the project running backend in Azure. We are running micro services /w ASPNET Core WebAPI and we have Angular 2 app talking to our API. We are using [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com) for Angular 2 development and Visual Studio 2017 for .NET related stuff.

If you are care about SEO there is such thing called [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) which is already part of the [Angular 4 core](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13822) (which is gonna be finally released like next week) which is taking care of server side rendering but you have to [setup your server](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal) to be able to handle that scenario.

Answer (score -2):

Issac... the short answer to your question is -- yes.

Theoretically you can in fact mix server-rendered templates (most likely you're referring to Razor templates) with client-rendered templates (HTML5 templates).

However, you **should not** mix server/client rendered templates for security purposes such as introducing a vector for XSS attacks.

Although this question is related to Angular 2.0, the AngularJS (1.x) [security docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security) explicitly state "Do not mix client and server templates". This concept still applies in Angular 2.0

Comment: How would it provide `XSS` more than just using angular or just using serverside views?